# Hacer que codigo funcione con boton si o no

Tags: javascript, script

Tengo este código que hace que le envié un mensaje de confirmación al usuario al querer salir de mi pagina web, todo funciona bien.

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(event) {
  var confirmationMessage = '¿Seguro que quieres salir?';

  event.returnValue = confirmationMessage;
  return confirmationMessage;
});
```

El problema es que quiero que ese código tenga un botón que diga " Si preguntar " y otro que diga " No Preguntar " y que al presionar no preguntar no me salga el mensaje de alerta al salir de la pagina

necesito que el codigo funcione con estos dos botones pero no se como hacerlo

```
<input type="button" value="Preguntar" onclick="bPreguntar = true;" >
<input type="button" value="No preguntar" onclick="bPreguntar = false;" >
```

Comment: has intentado sacr un modal en el cual tengas esos botones ?

Comment: Lo que quiero es modificar el codigo javascript a medida que pueda funcionar con los botones en true o false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tan solo deberías declarar una variable externa y luego utilizarla para saber si deberías mostrar o no la pregunta. Por ejemplo:

```js
var bPreguntar = true;

function mostrarPregunta(pregunta) {
  bPreguntar = pregunta;
}

window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(event) {
  if (bPreguntar) {
    var confirmationMessage = '¿Seguro que quieres salir?';

    event.returnValue = confirmationMessage;
    return confirmationMessage;
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Preguntar" onclick="mostrarPregunta(true)">
<input type="button" value="No preguntar" onclick="mostrarPregunta(false)">
```

Comment: Excelente amigo me funciono al 1000%